# Inheriting permissions in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I want to restrict some folders on my server so that only one user has access. This user has administrator rights, but is not the actual "Administrator" account.

When I try to modify Permissions for a folder, such as removing groups or user names from the Security tab, i get this message:

> You can't remove Administrators/Users because this object is
>   inheriting permissions from its parent. To remove
>   Administrators/Users, you must prevent this object from inheriting
>   permissions. Turn off the option for inheriting permissions, and then
>   try again.

Where do I go to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop the permissions from inheriting. You can do this by clicking Advanced on the Security tab and unchecking the box for inheritance.

Comment: what if I am the only user that has read&write access but now I get "Access is denied" because I need full access ?

Comment: If you're an administrator you can take ownership in the advanced tab and then change the permissions.